# Xamarin.Forms.Device.get_PlatformServices() Crash

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms App with an inside Webview. In my this Android are were some crashes, which are shown in the Google Play Console. Can someone help me with this?

Error message

```
android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: at Xamarin.Forms.Device.get_PlatformServices () [0x00007] in <68ab566bdacc435a8adf7cece6abb272>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Device.GetAssemblies () [0x00000] in <68ab566bdacc435a8adf7cece6abb272>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Initialize () [0x00008] in <68ab566bdacc435a8adf7cece6abb272>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get[T] (Xamarin.Forms.DependencyFetchTarget fetchTarget) [0x00000] in <68ab566bdacc435a8adf7cece6abb272>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Application..ctor () [0x0002b] in <68ab566bdacc435a8adf7cece6abb272>:0
at MeinEWE.App..ctor () [0x00000] in <7b249c0b0e004be3aa733910ee8dffd8>:0
at MeinEWE.Droid.StartActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x00007] in <018fe477438642d88af72a93fcfa16c1>:0
at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in <2b67a0b2f42248818afbd77843dff211>:0
at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.7(intptr,intptr,intptr)
  at md5725ec680625e4d82d39e64f30f8fe933.StartActivity.n_onCreate (Native Method)
  at md5725ec680625e4d82d39e64f30f8fe933.StartActivity.onCreate (StartActivity.java:29)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7327)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7318)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1275)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3101)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3264)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1955)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7076)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

I think the error happens inside the OnCreate method, but I don't know how to fix it:

MainActivity.cs

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
   ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

   FormsWebViewRenderer.Initialize();

   base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
   global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

   AnimationViewRenderer.Init();

   RequestedOrientation = !IsTablet ? ScreenOrientation.SensorPortrait : ScreenOrientation.SensorLandscape;

   Android.Webkit.WebView.SetWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);

   StartActivity(typeof(StartActivity));
}
```

StartActivity.cs

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            LoadApplication(new App());

            RequestedOrientation = !IsTablet ? ScreenOrientation.SensorPortrait : ScreenOrientation.SensorLandscape;
        }
```

Comment: Where is your `LoadApplication` method

Comment: Do you really need the `StartActivity`?? You don't seem to be using it anywhere

Comment: What I mean to say is you do not seem to be actually using it, Secondly, you are Initializing `Xamarin.Forms` in a different `Activity` and using `LoadApplication` method somewhere else which could be the reason for this.

Comment: This sounds logically. I think this seems redundant! I will try it out and test it. If someone else has another idea I would really like to hear it :)

Comment: Do that let me know if it makes any difference!!

Comment: @FreakyAli it worked, thank you!

Comment: You want me to add that as an answer? So you can mark it?